# How to create gutters between pages in a fluid-width carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm creating a custom carousel for my current project. Here's a simplified version (only tested in Chrome/Mac):

http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/LpQzbv

Note that when the carousel scrolls, you can see that each page (1-5) butts up flush against its neighbor on the left and right sides (looking like a single double-thick border). I'd like to add a 5px-wide gutter between the left and right borders of each page so that the borders don't touch.

However, since this is a fluid-width carousel, this has proven to be more difficult than expected.

I need to support IE9+, so I can't rely on [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) values or [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations); I'd probably need to do this via jQuery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), but when the horizontal position to which I'm animating is basically `100% + 5px`, I can't figure out how to express that in code.

How would I go about that? Is there, perhaps, another clever way to set up the carousel that allows me to use margins, padding, table cell padding, etc. to my benefit? Or, any other ideas? I've played around with different approaches for a couple of hours and I'm running out of ideas.

---

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarify what I mean by "gutter" - I'd like there to be a 5px empty gap between the left and right sides of each page in the carousel. Each page should retain its own borders, but there should be empty whitespace between them (only noticeable on scroll). Here's an example that uses calc() and CSS transitions to do exactly what I want (only tested in Chrome):

http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/GpQYPj

I just need to find a comparable solution that is compatible with IE9+ (which calc() and CSS animations are not).

Answer (score 0):

Applying `border-box` to everything will allow you to add paddings without breaking the layout.

```
// See an explanation here:
// http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/
html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, you were already doing this. Here is my take on it:

```
.window {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    // Add these two rules
    // The idea is to make a static frame, except for the right column
    // which is the one being repainted.
    border: 5px solid #666;
    border-right: 0;
}

...

.slider li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: table;
    border-right: 5px solid #666; // <- Paint the right column only
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using that - please see the example code.

Comment: :) sorry, my bad I missed that. I've edited my answer with an actual possible solution to your question. Hope it helps.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for your help; here's a CodePen with your edits: http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/MaQPBX. Unfortunately, that's not what I'm trying to achieve - sorry if my description wasn't clear. I updated the question with more details.